# How to use a consistent random sample in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, random

Below I have a code where a read a csv file and take a random sample of `700` from the file.
I need to do this on multiple files, but if I iterate over the files, the sample (as it is random) will be different for each file, wheras I want to keep it the same once it's randomly generated.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file.csv, delim_whitespace=True)
df_s = df.sample(n=700)
```

My ideas are to take the row number and then pass it to the next file, however this does not seem to be very elegant.

Do you know any good solutions to this issue?

**CLARIFICATION**

The file lengths are different, but there is a minimum file length: 750.

**desired outcome EXAMPLE**

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1.csv, delim_whitespace=True)
df_s1 = df1.sample(n=700) # choose random sample

df2 = pd.read_csv(file2.csv, delim_whitespace=True)
df_s2 = df2.sample(n=700) # use same random sample as above
```

Comment: Do they have the same shape?

Comment: They all have the same number of columns, but rows differ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use `random_state` parameter in [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html), but it works only if same sizes of all files, so add parameter `nrows` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file.csv, delim_whitespace=True, nrows=750)
df_s = df.sample(n=700, random_state=123)
```

Comment: How can the `np.random.seed(123)` help, as I don't see it being assigned anywhere. Could you please elaborate? Also `.sample` has a option `random_state`, but I am not sure what it does.

Comment: okay, could please show how to use it, as I tried both, but I cannot get he same sample size when I generate samples from the same data frame or different files.

Comment: I updated a clarifying comment, as the length, albeit different, has a minimum length. These questions, make me think it's actually more complex then  thought myself.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to set the `np.random.seed(123)`.

This has the advantage that it sets the random seed for all `pandas` functions at once.

[A more detail answer can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52375474/8307815)