# Is there a way to set random state for all pandas function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

As titled, it seems very didactic to set `random_state` for every randomness-related pandas function. Any way to set it only once to make sure the random state is set for all functions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526975/set-random-seed-programwide-in-python

Comment: This arg is optional, no?

Comment: @Wen Does this work with pandas?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes it is. But I am trying to make sure I could reproduce what I am doing, so I need to set random_state for every (applicable) function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pandas functions get their random source by calling pd.core.common._random_state, which accepts a single `state` argument, defaulting to None.  From its docs:

```
Parameters
----------
state : int, np.random.RandomState, None.
    If receives an int, passes to np.random.RandomState() as seed.
    If receives an np.random.RandomState object, just returns object.
    If receives `None`, returns np.random.
    If receives anything else, raises an informative ValueError.
    Default None.
```

So if it gets None, which is the default value for the caller's random_state, it returns the `np.random` module itself:

```
In [247]: pd.core.common._random_state(None)
Out[247]: <module 'numpy.random' from 'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\random\\__init__.py'>
```

and *it* will use the global numpy state.  So:

```
In [262]: np.random.seed(3)

In [263]: pd.Series(range(10)).sample(3).tolist()
Out[263]: [5, 4, 1]

In [264]: pd.DataFrame({0: range(10)}).sample(3)[0].tolist()
Out[264]: [3, 8, 2]

In [265]: np.random.seed(3)

In [266]: pd.Series(range(10)).sample(3).tolist()
Out[266]: [5, 4, 1]

In [267]: pd.DataFrame({0: range(10)}).sample(3)[0].tolist()
Out[267]: [3, 8, 2]
```

If any method doesn't respect this, it's a bug.

Comment: So whenever I set numpy's random seed and do not pass any sort of random_state to pandas operations, my code will still be deterministic based on np.random.seed. Is that right?

Comment: Correct, or at least that's the intent. :-)

Comment: Thanks!! Also, is there a connection between `np.random.seed` and `random.seed`?

Comment: @Mr.cysl, no they have separate internal states